# Using configmap for ports

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to use configMap values for port values like containerPort or targetPort?

Here's the possible example how it could work:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
        labels:
          app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: {{someImage}}
          ports:
            - name: CONTAINER_PORT
              containerPort:
                valueFrom:
                  configMapKeyRef:
                    name: auth-config
                    key: PORT
          env:
            - name: PORT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: auth-config
                  key: PORT
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not possible for the `ports` section.

You can use `env` keys in container's commands and args. Find more here: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/expansion.md

Usually most docker images have static port numbers encoded in the image with `EXPOSE` keyword, so having a dynamically configurable port is not a best practice from configuration standpoint. Try sticking to fixed port numbers as you can always remap them while exposing the port on Service.

Comment: I like ENV VARS for configuration so one method around the static port in Docker images is to use an ENV command in the Dockerfile, then EXPOSE that variable's port (so ENV APP_PORT 80, then EXPOSE $APP_PORT). In this way, you get a default port (ex. 80 in my example) and can change the port number at run time by setting an environment variable with Docker with the -e switch (ex. -e APP_PORT 9001).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I noticed the link is not available anymore.